# Magento Customer login and the backend login session

Tags: php, magento, session, cookies

I am here trying to find any Magento users faced the same problem with me and see if you guys have a solution for this.

I am using Magento Enterprise version and my a number of my customer cannot login. Some of the customer keep redirect to login page even they enter a correct username and password. It happens on those browser with my site cookie already, and after I clean my browser cookie for my site then I do not face the problem and I can login correctly. And after someday, I faced the login problem with the same browser again.

My session saving in db

and my cookie setting as below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv7p2.png

Do any Magento users face with the same problem and what is your solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using custom theme?
If you are then it is most likely that your theme is missing formkey.
Please check in [yourthemepath]/customer/form/login.phtml, it needs to have something like:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

inside `<form class=form-login...>  </form>`

Comment: Thanks William and I am sure I have include this code to login form. I can login after I clear my browser cookie.

Comment: Do you use any caching module?

Comment: I used Enterpise FPC without extra plugin and I tested login when disabled cache, no luck

Comment: hmm, weird. just a wild guess but do you have persistent module turned on? if so please check as well, /persistent/customer/form/login.phtml.
If I remember correctly, /persistent/customer/form/login.phtml will be used even if you disabled it in the admin, gotta change <active>false</active> in Mage_Persistent.xml. Happened to me once.

Comment: I had checked the potential reasons of sign in issues, it is proved that the cause of issue is not by Magento Cache. It's about Magento/PHP session storage to clients' browser. Normally it would not be a problem, however, I observed after I switched Magento session storage method from database to files OR files to database would cause problem of sign in for those browsers visited previously, to the website.

Comment: Steps to replicate the problem:

Step 1) Client visit Magento which using database for storing session, he/she create an account/ login successfully, a cookie will be set to client's browser by server
Step 2) I changed storing from db to files
Step 3) Client visit the site again and problem occurs even he/she put a correct username and password